# perl html treebuilder not returning string

Tags: perl

When I use

```
my ($key, $seperator, $value) = map $_->as_text, $row->content_list;
```

I get horribly nasty output back.

```
$VAR1 = 'Numberáofásourceálines';
$VAR2 = 'á23182';
$VAR3 = 'Htmlágeneratedáat';
$VAR4 = 'áMonáJuná13á11:06:46á2011';
$VAR5 = 'Coverageáview';
$VAR6 = 'áAsáinstrumented';
$VAR7 = 'Symboláfile(s)';
```

If I try `as_html` it's more decent but needs to get parsed...

```
$VAR1 = '<td class="red">TER</td>';
$VAR2 = '<td class="red">&nbsp;<strong>43%</strong>&nbsp;(function)</td>';
$VAR3 = '<td class="black">Threshold&nbsp;percent</td>';
$VAR4 = '<td class="black">&nbsp;<strong>100</strong>&nbsp;%</td>';
$VAR5 = '<td class="black">Number&nbsp;of&nbsp;source&nbsp;lines</td>';
$VAR6 = '<td class="black">&nbsp;23182</td>';
```

EDIT
     Unknown PerlIO layer 'encoding(cpActive' at myscript.pl line 27
    Unknown PerlIO layer 'code' at myscript.pl line 27
    Unknown PerlIO layer 'page:' at myscript.pl line 27
    Unknown PerlIO layer '437)' at myscript.pl line 27
    Cannot find encoding "cpActive :code :page: :437" at C:/Perl/lib/open.pm line 120.
    Cannot find encoding "cpActive :code :page: :437" at C:/Perl/lib/open.pm line 128.

Comment: `as_text` is returning exactly the right thing, but you're managing to mangle the encoding somewhere, and turning `U+00A0 NO-BREAK SPACE` into `U+00E1 LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH ACUTE`

Comment: I don't generate the html file i'm reading here, should i change encoding before reading?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your nasty output if the result of you not properly encoding your text on output. If you're printing to STDOUT, the following should do the trick:

```
use open ':std', ':locale';
```

Or on Windows:

```
sub acp { my ($cp) = `chcp` =~ /([0-9]+)/; $cp }
use open ':std', ':encoding(cp'.acp().')';
```

Comment: Hey thanks but can't seem to get it working on windows please see edit

Comment: I ended up doing $testValue =~ s/\x{a0}//g; is that bad? It's the value that was shown when I did a dump.

Comment: @user391986, *shrug*, whatever you want. You still need to properly encode your output, though.

Comment: @user391986, Sorry, didn't see the message saying the Windows version didn't work. Fixed it. I was going for memory since I'm not on Windows here. I still am.